# DOM object not becoming a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come I cannot make $(frame) a jQuery object in the below case?
Below is my output from chrome developer tools.

```
console: mainFrame
output: <frame src=​"http:​/​/someurl.com" name=​"mainFrame">​
console: $(mainFrame).contents()
output: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLFrameElement]' is not a valid selector.
```

**Edit:**

to respond to comments...

```
$.toString()
"function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }"

typeof(mainFrame)
"object"

jQuery
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: Could you provide relevant code instead of console output?!

Comment: What is the output of `$.toString()` and `typeof mainFrame`?

Comment: I think the problem is that this is a frame tag and if you're not on the same domain then it is a security violation. If you are you might still need to add some context like the following:
$('#myselector',top.frames["mainFrame"].document).contents();

Comment: I don't think `$` is jQuery here, try `jQuery(mainFrame).contents()`

Comment: It looks like jQuery doesn't support frame elements: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-should-support-frame-elements-equally-to-iframe-elements

Comment: Updated my question!
Thanks so much for all the help.
So it looks like `$` still works as a selector but it's not actually `jQuery`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery doesn't seem to be included in your document. Some browsers set `$` to `querySelector` by default (which is a native way to select elements of the DOM using css-like syntax), thereby your error message. Try adding

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jQuery is not included into the DOM, try to include jQuery either by CDN or add standalone jQuery into the DOM.

You can confirm the jQuery installation by typing `$` into the *browser inspect tab.*
If the output is something like

```
> $
ƒ (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}
```

then jQuery added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(frame).contents();
```

Or

```
$("html", frame);
```

not sure which one will work.